Analytic Function Sending Disk to Disk has |a_0|^2+|a_1| at most 1
I am working on the following old qualifying exam problem:
Suppose that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$. Prove that $|a_0|^2+|a_1|\leq 1$. In addition, determine all $f$ that satisfy $|a_0|^2+|a_1|=1$.
I really struggle with this type of problem that seems to rely solely on facts about holomorphic/analytic functions. I know Hadamard's formula, which says that the radius of convergence $R$ satisfies $$1/R= \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$$.
I know that if $|z|<1$, then $|f(z)|=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n||z|^n\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$.
Beyond this I'm stuck.
